# Checkedlistbox items with a logo

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a checkedlistbox that shows items imported from an excel.

Is it possible to add a logo icon, next to the text of each item?

I am working on windows forms.

Answer (score 0):

OP:

> Is it possible to add a logo icon, next to the text of each item?

No.

However you might want to consider using a [`ListView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview?view=net-5.0) with the [`View`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.view?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_ListView_View) property set to [`View.Details`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.view?view=net-5.0).  Here you can display checkboxes as well as an additional image via `ListViewItem.ImageIndex`.

### More

- [ListViewItem.ImageIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.imageindex?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_ListViewItem_ImageIndex)
- [ListView Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview?view=net-5.0)